# iptables: use the ssh tunnel?

Tags: iptables

The mission: set a ssh tunnel at port 7777
Use iptables to re-direct port 80 to port 7777
That way my web browsers can use the ssh tunnel

Establish a ssh tunnel:

```
ssh -D 7777 -fCN user@remote_ip
```

My iptables:

> cat /etc/sysconfig/iptables

```
*nat
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
:INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
-A OUTPUT -d 127.0.0.1/32 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 7777
COMMIT
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
-A INPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -j ACCEPT
COMMIT
```

however it does not seem to be working. my web browser is not showing my remote server's IP ( ssh tunnel's )

**UPDATE..**

forget testing it with web browsers.. this wget command should be printing my ssh tunnel's IP. but it is not. ( it's printing my real IP. )

```
  wget -qO- http://ipecho.net/plain ; echo
```

wget uses port 80 also.

Comment: totally wrong usage of socks proxy protocol. Set socks proxy in your browser's settings not via iptables.

Comment: then use [tsocks](http://tsocks.sourceforge.net/)

Answer (score 1):

You can add it below `*nat` block.

`*filter` means filter table which is the default if you haven't specified any table.

Comment: where does it go ? I tried.

Comment: recreate the file with `iptables-save`, if you don't understand the format.